# Show that the manifold $Z_4 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 28\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness

I would like to show that the manifold,

$$
Z_4 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 28\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3
$$

is not compact.

Because $Z_4 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, compact means closed and bounded.

Clearly, $Z_4$ is closed by the continuous map,
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (x,y,z) \rightarrow x^3 + y^3 + z^3
$$

Indeed, $Z_4$ is the reciprocal image of $\{28\}$ by the continuous map $f$.

Therefore, because $\{28\}$ is closed, $Z_4$ is also closed.

So, that means that I have to show that $Z_4$ is not bounded.

Let $z = (28 - x^3 - y^3)^{1/3}$. We see that there will always be a choice of $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that there won't be any $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z \leq M$.

Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, but a better/more direct way of phrasing it is that for any real $x$, the point $(x, - x, 28^{1/3})$ lies in the set. Hence it is unbounded.

Comment: The point $(m, 28^{1/3}, -m)$ is in the manifold for all $m\in \mathbb{R}$.